# Interpretation of a valuation function when we have a known truth and an assumed truth in a proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

To provide context, I am currently learning about *Conditional Introduction*. This is the first time in this propositional calculus unit that I have encountered an **assumed truth** ; previously, all premises have simply been evaluated as **known truths**.

Here is a picture to provide further clarification:
[image: Conditional Implication Example]

The conditional introduction itself is not confusing. However, what IS confusing is the idea that a premise and an assumption are being classified as different entities. My confusion is as follows:

When it comes to a valuation function, what is the difference between "Assuming" a truth value and "Knowing" a truth value. Using the above picture, we "know" that the premise $R$ is true....under some value function $v_i$. However, when we say that we "Assume" $Z$ is true...this is presumably the truth value being assigned under the same value function $v_i$.

If these statements are being evaluated using the same value function, why is it that one statement's truth value ($R$) is "known" but the other statement's truth value ($Z$) is "assumed"? Is the idea that we do not know the full extent of $v_i$'s mapping strategy?

Comment: Is the derivation roundabout intentionally? As a "hint", you should *never* need to have a proof where an introduction rule is immediately followed by an elimination rule for the same connective, here $\land$. (This is a property of natural deduction called "local soundness".)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. My question is about what an "Assumption" means. My question is not about the proof...I merely used this proof as an example.

Comment: I understand that. If you copied this example from somewhere, it's (depending on context) a bit silly. If you wrote this proof and you added lines 3 and 4 because you felt they were necessary, that suggests a misunderstanding. If you added it for some other reason, I'm not sure what that reason is. If you just randomly added stuff to the subproof, I again don't know the motivation for that would be. It doesn't matter for the question you're asking, but if you saw someone arbitrarily multiply $\frac{2}{2}$ during a calculation only to immediately cancel it out, you'd wonder why they did that.

Comment: Oh...this is what the lecturer presented. This is not my work.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion between syntax and semantics here: what do you think valuation functions have to do with formal proofs?

Comment: I guess the way I looked at it is the "R" is functioning as an object that has guaranteed truth. As far as I understand, when you ascribe "truth" to something, you are effectively looking at this object through the lens of a particular value function. Regardless, to address your overarching comment, if the difference between syntax and semantics is what I am missing, I would greatly appreciate the insight as to why I am thinking about this incorrectly.

Comment: @Derek Elkins A roundabout like this would be necessary if 1) the proof system has no rule for reiteration -- with it, $R$ could be repeated on line 3 without forming and immediately elimiating a conjunction first, but not all rule systems explicitly mention such a reiteration rule, and 2) the $\to I$ rule is understood such that the subproof $R \vdash Z$ is required to legitimate the prepending of $Z \to$ (so $R$ can not just be weakened by a random antecedent $Z$ which doesn't occur as an assumption anywhere). Still, it seems like a not very instructive example of how to use $\to I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can look at the assumption on line 2 as an "additional assumption". It is temporary unlike the premises. It will be discharged on 5 when we close the subproof from lines 2 to 4 replacing it with that conditional proposition.

Here is how the authors of the [*forallx* logic textbook](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf) describe what is going on. (page 107)

> The general pattern at work here is the following. We first make an additional assumption, A; and from that additional assumption, we prove B. In that case, we know the following: If A,then B.

---

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Comment: What do you mean, "Additional Assumption". What is the "original assumption"? Is the "original assumption" the premise $R$?

Comment: @S.Cramer Right. The original assumptions would be premises, if any, that are accepted at the beginning of the proof. An additional assumption is used to start a subproof. It is discharged when the subproof is closed. If one did not close the subproof one would have to add that additional assumption to the premises, but generally one wants to close all those subproofs.